# INSERT the value of TotalPrice by calculating automatically by (quantity*price) from Items table and Order table

Tags: sql-server, left-join, sql-insert

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Price FLOAT
)

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    [Address] VARCHAR(200),
    Contact VARCHAR(50),
)

CREATE TABLE Orders
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(Id),
    ItemId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Items(Id),
    Quantity INT,
    TotalPrice FLOAT
)
```

Comment: You can use a trigger to handle this requirement.  Each time an order gets inserted, the trigger can lookup the item price, and then populate the `TotalPrice` column.

Answer (score -1):

As Tim mentioned, you could use a trigger to make this work. That would't be a good overall solution though. If it has to happen in the database (it might be better not in here), you'd be better to make a stored procedure, and call it, and let it do the work that's needed where it involves those other tables.

Also, just a heads up that float is a poor choice for data type when you're storing money values. I've got a detailed post about that here:

https://blog.greglow.com/2018/01/15/sql-newbie-mistake-1-using-float-instead-decimal/